# Hadoop TeraSort not using all cluster nodes

Tags: hadoop

### Question

Regarding the TeraSort demo in hadoop, please suggest if the symptom is as expected or the workload should be distributed.

### Background

Started Hadoop (3 nodes in a cluster) and run the TeraSort benchmark as below in **Executions**.

I expected all 3 nodes would get busy and all CPU would be utilized (400% in top). However only the node on which the job started got busy and the CPU was not fully utilized. For example if it is started on sydspark02, top shows as below.

I wonder this is as expected or if there is a configuration issue by which the workload is not distributed among the nodes.

**sydspark02**

```
top - 13:37:12 up 5 days,  2:58,  2 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.06, 0.12
Tasks: 134 total,   1 running, 133 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27.5 us,  2.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 69.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8175980 total,  1781888 used,  6394092 free,       68 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   532116 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2602 hadoop    20   0 2191288 601352  22988 S 120.7  7.4   0:15.52 java
 1197 hadoop    20   0  105644    976      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.16 sshd
 2359 hadoop    20   0 2756336 270332  23280 S   0.3  3.3   0:08.87 java
```

**sydspark01**

```
top - 13:38:32 up 2 days, 19:28,  2 users,  load average: 0.15, 0.07, 0.11
Tasks: 141 total,   1 running, 140 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.6 id,  2.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  10240364 total, 10092352 used,   148012 free,      648 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  8527904 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
10635 hadoop    20   0 2766264 238540  23160 S   3.0  2.3   0:11.15 java
11353 hadoop    20   0 2770680 287504  22956 S   1.0  2.8   0:08.97 java
11057 hadoop    20   0 2888396 327260  23068 S   0.7  3.2   0:12.42 java
```

**sydspark03**

```
top - 13:44:21 up 5 days,  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 124 total,   1 running, 123 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.7 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   8175980 total,  4552876 used,  3623104 free,     1156 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  3818884 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
29374 hadoop    20   0 2729012 204180  22952 S   3.0  2.5   0:07.47 java
```

### Executions

```
> sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [sydspark01]
sydspark01: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-sydspark01.out
sydspark03: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-sydspark03.out
sydspark02: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-sydspark02.out
sydspark01: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-sydspark01.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-sydspark01.out

> sbin/start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-sydspark01.out
sydspark01: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-sydspark01.out
sydspark03: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-sydspark03.out
sydspark02: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-sydspark02.out

> hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar teragen 100000000 /user/hadoop/terasort-input
> hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar terasort /user/hadoop/terasort-input /user/hadoop/terasort-output
```

### Configuration files

**slaves**

```
sydspark01
sydspark02
sydspark03
```

**core-sites.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/home/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://sydspark01:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

## Environment

Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 4CPU on VMWare
Hadoop 2.7.3
 
Java 8

## Monitoring with JMC

When running the JMC on the data node in the node where the job is executed.

**CPU**

Only about 25% of CPU resource (1 CPU out of 4) is used.

[image]

**Memory**

[image]

## Yarn

```
$ yarn node -list
16/10/03 15:36:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at sydspark01/143.96.102.161:8032
Total Nodes:3
         Node-Id             Node-State Node-Http-Address       Number-of-Running-Containers
sydspark03:57249              RUNNING sydspark03:8042                                  0
sydspark02:42220              RUNNING sydspark02:8042                                  0
sydspark01:50445              RUNNING sydspark01:8042                                  0
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
            <value>sydspark01:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>sydspark01:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
            <value>sydspark01:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
            <value>sydspark01:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
            <value>sydspark01:8033</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How many cores does yarn use? You can check it on yarn's web ui  address http://sydspark01:8088 or executing command `yarn node -list`. And please post your yarn's config file yarn-site.xml

Comment: @maxteneff, thanks for the comment. Added the information at the bottom.

Comment: There are 0 cpus in use. Did you run `yarn node -list` during running mapreduce job?